# How to resolve multiple values in one column in a table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

I have been tasked with designing a database from a scenario. However, while designing my solution I found I would have multiple values in one cell. We were told this is a repeating group and should be avoided in a database.

I get the repeating groups when I want to link the songs on an album to the album they are found on. For instance, there can be one or many songs on an album. However, a song could be on one or many albums (Dean Martin - Silver Bells could be on a Christmas Hits album and a Dean Martin album).

If I reference each song to its album I would use the AlbumId as a foreign key. However, if it was in multiple albums then I would have multiple AlbumId's as the foreign key. This gives me a repeating group as there will be multiple Ids in the same cell.

If this was reversed by storing all the album's songs on the Album entity I would have the same issue as the SongId would be a foreign key and each album will have multiple SongId's in the same cell.

The design I have includes these following entities:

> song

and

> album

The song entity will contain the following attribute types:

> - SongId (PK)
> - SongDuration
> - AlbumId (FK)
> - AudioFileSize
> - AudioFile
> - SongTitle
> - SongLyrics
> - SongNotes

The album entity will contain the following attribute types:

> - AlbumId (PK)
> - AlbumTitle
> - NumOfTracks
> - ReleaseDate
> - ProductionLabel (FK) //Goes to another table that has no issues.
> - AlbumCoverImage
> - CoverImageStory
> - AmountOfCDs

I am quite new to database design and I feel I have grasped it well. However, I am puzzled on how to solve this.

If any more information on the database is required I will happily provide it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Steve.

Comment: Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We were told this is a repeating group and should be avoided in a database.

Not "avoided", but modelled, solved.  Each column must be Atomic:

- 1NF: no multiple or compound values
- 2NF: no repeating groups

The simple solution is to model the multiple values in a subordinate table.  In this case, with two Identifers `Song` and `Album`, an Associative table.

> `RecordID`

That is the first and foremost error.  It cripples both the modelling exercise, and the resulting "database".

The *Relational Model* requires:

1. the Key must be *"made up from the data"*
   (ie. not an manufactured ID; GUID; UUID; etc, none of which are data)
2. each row (as distinct from a record with a `RecordId`) in each table must be unique
   Data uniqueness cannot be obtained from a ID; GUID; UUID; etc.  Further, the stupid thing is always an **additional column and index**.

That needs to be corrected.

Third, you have some columns in the wrong tables.

### Album Data Model

Modelling is substantially cheaper than trying SQL.  See if this satisfies the requirement.
[image: Album Data Model]
Rather than going back-and-forth bringing you up to speed with Relational Databases, I have fixed up all issues.  Eg. you have multiple CDs per Album, but that was not handled or requested, it must be resolved.

Also available in **[PDF](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/SteveG1%20DM.pdf)**.

It is rendered in IDEF1X, the Standard for modelling a Relational Database.  You may find the short **[Introduction to IDEF1X](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPeters. Re "removed unconstructive criticism". As evidenced, OP is confused, as is 95% of the SO readership. Precisely because the "relational" textbooks are anti-relational and confused. If you remove my explanation, it subtracts meaning and an answer to OP's posted quandary. When you go around removing anything that "criticises" those you believe in, you ensure that the problem continues.  Evidenced facts are evidenced facts, they are not changed by opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You have a many-to-many relationship.  So, you can use a junction/association table:

```
create table songAlbums (
    . . .,
    songId int references songs(songId),
    albumId int references albums(albumId),
    . . .
)
```

You might want to include other information, such as the position on the album.  Such a table could have a composite primary key `(songId, albumId)` or a synthetic primary key (`generated always as identity`).

Comment: Record IDs `songId`;  `albumId`; etc, are "generated always", the same puke as GUID; UUID; etc.  They cannot provide row uniqueness.  They are always one additional column and one additional index.